# Is it normal to have a server mother board with 2 ethernet (RJ45) ports using different drivers?

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet, freebsd

I have a ASRock Rack `E3C236D2I - Mini-ITX` motherboard that comes with two `2 x RJ45 Ethernet` ports. I put this motherboard in a little server I'm using to run TrueNas Core (FreeBSD) on.

I noticed that one Ethernet jack is using the `em` driver the other is using the `igb` driver.

So I'm wondering if this is a problem. Both ports work fine and I don't notice much difference in speeds (although it's hard to tell with my slow home network) but the point is, does make sense to do? And if not should I switch them to use the same driver. If so which would be the preferred one to use.

Comment: Even with a single port, I've seen two different drivers on some systems. Unless something is broke, or one port operates much better than the other, I'd leave things unchanged. Also, before you make *any* change, image the whole disk, lest the OS become unusable.

Comment: Your motherboard has three RJ45 ports according to the website, one for the i210 and the other for the Intel® i219, the third port is a BMC port.

Comment: Yeah I noticed the third BMC port, but I had no idea what that was for and how to exactly use it.